# Autenticação e permissão de Usuários com MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em MVC 3, utilizando C# para as Models e Controllers e Razor com HTML para as Views.
Eu quero implementar a autenticação e permissão de usuários ao sistema.
Como posso fazer isso utilizando os recursos que o MVC disponibiliza para controle de usuários?(Se é que existe).
Tem como fazer?

Comment: enquanto uma boa resposta não vem, posso te adiantar uma previsão http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resposta:

Sim, é possível.

## Explicação:

Se você está começando com o [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) sugiro que pesquise sobre a Classe `FormsAuthentication`, para autenticação do usuário e a classe `AuthorizeAttribute` para realizar o controle de acesso.

## Referência:

> Este link abaixo é de um artigo que, pelo que interpretei da sua pergunta, cai como uma luva para o que você precisa.
>
> http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-autenticacao-basica/20255

Comment: Tome muito cuidado ao postar respostas com apenas links como informação, pois caso o link quebre sua resposta automaticamente se torna nula e inútil. Você deve escrever as informações relevantes aqui no StackOverflow, em sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, sou novo aqui. Editei a resposta e gostaria de saber se preciso melhorá-la ainda mais.

Comment: Disponha, porém, a pergunta sobre saber se precisa melhorar a resposta ainda mais, isso vai de você, se você acha que deve melhorar, respostas melhores são sempre muito bem vindas aqui no StackOverflow, quanto melhor for, e quanto mais especificada for sua resposta, mais pontos de reputação você ganhará por ela, pois usuários verão que é uma resposta correta, útil e clara, por isso irão aumentar +1. Outra dica é formatar bem a sua resposta, envolvendo em "`" para destacar código ou nome de Classes, negrito no que for importante, e talvez "#" para Cabeçalhos (famoso h1,h2,h3), ou ">" p/ citação

Comment: Vou editar sua resposta e veja como ela melhor ficaria formatada.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo Roberto.